# Combine MagnificPopup with ElevateZoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all you JavaScript/jquery gurus out there.

I hope someone is able to help me since I am pretty much stuck trying to combine [MagnificPopup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) with [ElevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom).

I am able to get ElevateZoom to work if there is only one image. But in gallery mode (several images) then it fails badly.

Here is an example of it working with one image.

[image]

You can see the image behind the popup. If there are several images it does not Work.

I have made a few changes to magnificpopup.js :

In "open: function(data){..."

I have added

```
$(".mfp-img").elevateZoom();
```

just before

```
return data;
```

In "getImage: function (item, template) {..."

I have added

```
var att = document.createAttribute('data-zoom-image');
att.value = item.src;
img.setAttributeNode(att);
```

just before

```
item.img = $(img).on('load.mfploader', onLoadComplete).on('error.mfploader', onLoadError);
img.src = item.src;
```

This Works well but only with one image. As soon as there are more it fails. Unfortunately I am not able to figure out the modification needed myself. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best regards

Nicki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

Instead of the code i added above, I did the following:

In "getImage: function (item, template) {..."

Just before

```
_mfpTrigger('ImageLoadComplete');
```

I have added

```
$("#" + item.img[0].id).elevateZoom();
```

In "close: function () {..."

Just before

```
mfp.isOpen = false;
```

I have added

```
$('.zoomContainer').remove();
```

In "getImage: function (item, template) {..."

I have added

```
img.id = item.el[0].id;
var att = document.createAttribute('data-zoom-image');
att.value = item.src;
img.setAttributeNode(att);
```

just before

```
item.img = $(img).on('load.mfploader', onLoadComplete).on('error.mfploader', onLoadError);
img.src = item.src;
```

Now everything Works regardless of the number of images used.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

thank you for this walkthrough!
I would suggest to add the

```
$('.zoomContainer').remove();
```

also at the beginning of "getImage: function (item, template) {...",
so there is only one zoomContainer, when you slide through several images.